# Efficient real-time plotting using Plot.ly

Tags: javascript, plotly

I push data from node.js using socketio to the visualization website. The desired interval is 1ms.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="tester" style="width:90%;height:70%;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        console.log("testing")
        TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');

        var N = 1000


        signals = {
            time: [],
            top:  [],
            bottom: []
        };

        var layout = {
            yaxis: {range:[0, 1024]}
        }

        var socket = io();

        console.log("Set up succefully!")

        socket.on('data', function (msg) {
            if (signals.time.length > N) {
                signals.time.shift();
                signals.top.shift();
                signals.bottom.shift();
            }

            signals.time.push(msg['time'])
            signals.top.push(msg['top'])
            signals.bottom.push(msg['bottom'])

            var trace1 = {  x: signals.time,
                            y: signals.top}

            var trace2 = {  x: signals.time,
                            y: signals.bottom}

            Plotly.newPlot( TESTER, [trace1, trace2], layout);
        });
    }

</script>
```

This works if I set the interval to be 1s. If I set it smaller than 0.5s, the whole page is not responding. I checked in the chrome application, and can see the socket io frames arriving. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: are you a 'pro' member? you might get better luck asking on their community forums. This might be a limitation set by the service instead of a js problem.

Comment: Hmm I'm running the offline version (not through the API). I'm guessing that the display doesn't render fast enough, but even if I only render every 100th samples, it's still not working

Comment: did you change N to less than 500 when you changed the time to 0.5?